# Solve Imaginary Complex Equation

Tags: complex-numbers

**Solve the equation**

Question 1:

iz^2+(2−8i)z+4+20i=0

Question 2:

z^4 − 8z^2 + 25 = 0.

Comment: Are you familiar with the quadratic formula? It applies for complex coefficients ($a, b, c$) too. The first is already a quadratic. The second one is just a quadratic in disguise. Put $z^2 = y$.

Comment: Probably beside the point, but don't talk yourself down too much. It's not because exercises don't work immediatly that you're bad in mathematics. Try easier questions first (i'm sure your exercise bundle is ordered somehow from easy to somewhat harder/ equal exercises bundled in series). Try to link exercises to you coursenotes... You will not learn much from people telling you the answer. Instead you'll learn much more from trying yourself and experiencing what works/ does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: The first one is  quadratic equation and the formula for the solution is same whether the coefficients are real or complex. For the second one put $\zeta =z^{2}$ and solve the resulting quadratic equation in $\zeta$. Then take square root.

Answer (score 0):

Using the quadratic Formula we get
$$z_1=2-2i$$ or $$z_2=6+4i$$